# Spark/Scala: Operations on some components from a DataFrame with Array typed column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let me explain what I want to achieve with an example.
Starting with a DataFrame as following:

```
val df = Seq((1, "CS", 0, (0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)), 
             (4, "Ed", 0, (0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6)),
             (7, "CS", 0, (0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7)),
             (101, "CS", 1, (0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8)),
             (5, "CS", 1, (0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9)))
             .toDF("id", "dept", "test", "array")
+---+----+----+--------------------+
| id|dept|test|               array|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
```

I want to change some elements of the array column according to the information in id, dept and test column. I first add the Index to each row for different dept as following:

```
@transient val w = Window.partitionBy("dept").orderBy("id")
val tempdf = df.withColumn("Index", row_number().over(w))
tempdf.show
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
| id|dept|test|               array|Index|
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|    1|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|    2|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|    3|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|    4|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|    1|
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
```

What I want to achieve is to minus a constant (0.1) from one element in array column with its location corresponds to the index of the row within each dept. For example, in "dept==CS" case, the **final result** should be:

```
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
| id|dept|test|               array|Index|
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|    1|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9]|    2|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.7]|    3|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7]|    4|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|    1|
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
```

Currently, I am thinking of achieving this with udf as following:

```
def subUdf = udf((array: Seq[Double], dampFactor: Double, additionalIndex: Int) => additionalIndex match{
   case 0 => array
   case _ => { val temp = array.zipWithIndex
     var mask = Array.fill(array.length)(0.0)
     mask(additionalIndex-1) = dampFactor
     val tempAdj = temp.map(x => if (additionalIndex == (x._2+1)) (x._1-mask, x._2) else x)
       tempAdj.map(_._1)
             }
      }
  )
val dampFactor = 0.1
val finaldf = tempdf.withColumn("array", subUdf(tempdf("array"), dampFactor, when(tempdf("dept") === "CS" && tempdf("test") === 0, tempdf("Index")).otherwise(lit(0)))).drop("Index")
```

The udf has a compile error due to the overloading method:

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:34: error: overloaded method value - with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Double <and>
  (x: Long)Double <and>
  (x: Int)Double <and>
  (x: Char)Double <and>
  (x: Short)Double <and>
  (x: Byte)Double
 cannot be applied to (Array[Double])
            val tempAdj = temp.map(x => if (additionalIndex == (x._2+1)) (x._1-mask, x._2) else x)
           ^
```

Two related questions:

1. How to resolve the compile error?
2. I am open to suggestion of using method other than udf to achieve this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can create a UDF that takes the dampFactor, the array column and the window index column to transform the dataframe as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "CS", 0, Seq(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)), 
  (4, "Ed", 0, Seq(0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6)),
  (7, "CS", 0, Seq(0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7)),
  (101, "CS", 1, Seq(0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8)),
  (5, "CS", 1, Seq(0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9))
).toDF("id", "dept", "test", "array")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("dept").orderBy("id")
val tempdf = df.withColumn("index", row_number().over(w))

def adjustSeq(dampFactor: Double) = udf(
  (seq: Seq[Double], index: Int) =>
    seq.indices.map(i =>
      if (i == index - 1) seq(i) - dampFactor else seq(i)
    )
)

val finaldf = tempdf.
  withColumn("array", adjustSeq(0.1)($"array", $"index")).
  drop("index")

finaldf.show(false)
// +---+----+----+------------------------------------+
// |id |dept|test|array                               |
// +---+----+----+------------------------------------+
// |1  |CS  |0   |[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]                |
// |5  |CS  |1   |[0.4, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9]                |
// |7  |CS  |0   |[0.2, 0.5, 0.30000000000000004, 0.7]|
// |101|CS  |1   |[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7000000000000001] |
// |4  |Ed  |0   |[0.30000000000000004, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|
// +---+----+----+------------------------------------+
```

Your sample code appears to include some additional logic not described in the requirement:

> val finaldf = tempdf.withColumn("array", subUdf(tempdf("array"),
>   dampFactor, when(tempdf("dept") === "CS" && tempdf("test") === 0,
>   tempdf("Index")).otherwise(lit(0)))).drop("Index")

To factor in the additional logic:

```
def adjustSeq(dampFactor: Double) = udf(
  (seq: Seq[Double], index: Int, dept: String, test: Int) =>
    (`dept`, `test`) match {
      case ("CS", 0) =>
        seq.indices.map(i =>
          if (i == index - 1) seq(i) - dampFactor else seq(i)
        )
      case _ => seq
    }
)

val finaldf = tempdf.
  withColumn("array", adjustSeq(0.1)($"array", $"index", $"dept", $"test")).
  drop("index")

finaldf.show(false)
// +---+----+----+------------------------------------+
// |id |dept|test|array                               |
// +---+----+----+------------------------------------+
// |1  |CS  |0   |[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]                |
// |5  |CS  |1   |[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]                |
// |7  |CS  |0   |[0.2, 0.5, 0.30000000000000004, 0.7]|
// |101|CS  |1   |[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]                |
// |4  |Ed  |0   |[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]                |
// +---+----+----+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, your understanding is correct, including the additional logic part. I have a relatively shallow understanding that UDF is not optimized by Catalyst optimizer in Spark. But for this question, there is not a obvious solution that I can come up now. Can you comment how often is UDF used in practice and do we need to worry too much for using a lot of UDFs ?

Comment: You're right that Spark's built-in SQL functions would generally perform better than UDF, hence whenever applicable one should pick built-in functions over UDF.  For complex data transformations not covered by Spark's built-in function sets, UDF does open up the vast Scala API library (when using Scala).  Since both Spark and Scala run on JVM (and Spark is written in Scala), UDF in Scala is already subject to the least performance penalty.